# How to access excel headers using OLEDB using C#

Tags: c#, excel

i am creating a test cases for number of different test cases and each test case have id to it and i am trying to read the test data from the excel...

here is the layout of my excel sheet and not sure how else to come up with the right design

[image: Test Cases]

here is the code i'm reading:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
    string testCaseName = "case_1";
    string query = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$] WHERE test_case_id =\"" + testCaseName + "\"";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Problem:

The `test_case_id == 001_test` works fine without any problem

but if pass the `test_case_id = 0059_test` then I'm getting the data for the same `test_case_id` which is `0059_test` but I'am not getting the header correct header name, i am getting the header for the `test_case_id 001_test`

My Question: How can I GET the header for the particular `test_case_id` (intro_text, api_text...._ ?

Comment: Your data in Excel needs to be in a regular table format.  You should have only one row of headers.

Comment: i know,... but i have a requirements that requires to read multiple headers

Comment: I think you're going to have to read all of the data into a table and process it separately. Depending on how much data you have and how many test cases there are, I might think about building a list of each header ID that references the row number, then you could just do a lookup on the list. Have a look at the answer I provided to this question: [Is there a way to find a range...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948392/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-range-within-a-range-in-excel-csharp)

Comment: I agree with Sid.  You cannot use the OleDb approach for this task.

Answer (score 0):

By default first row is taken as header row. You need to specify the header row in the query.

*e.g.*: for **test_case_id  0059_test header row number is 3** then you have to write the query as follows:

```
string query = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$A3:C] WHERE test_case_id = \"" + testCaseName + "\"";
```

Where A3 is the first column header and C is last data column.